Gardena retractable reel garden hose
When mounting the reel, for the Gardena hose reel, can you adjust the hose length from the reel to the spigot?

Probably not made to be adjustable, but a garden hose repair kit plus some hose should work.

what do the installation instructions say?

Or use a short extension hose, such as a washing machine hose with a coupler.
